# How to run hello world program using spring maven?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

I have started to learn spring and trying to create simple hello world application using maven in sts.
Please anyone what am doing wrong in this code?

**index.jsp :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"

pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring4 MVC -HelloWorld</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello : ${name}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>    
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">       
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 </servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
 <listener-class>
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 </listener-class>
 </listener>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">     
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.helloworld" />     
 <bean
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix">
 <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
 </property>
 <property name="suffix">
 <value>index.jsp</value>
 </property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

**HelloWorldController.java :**

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {     
    /**
     * @param name
     * @param model
     * @return string
     */
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
     public String hello(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("name", name);
     return "helloworld";
     }
}
```

This is my code and when am trying to run this in browser i got message "The requested resource is not available." Please anyone tell me what i have done wrong ?Thanks

Comment: How r u trying to run this project ?

Comment: first i take maven build and run on server

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access? Is there a application root? What is the server? Are there any errors in the server log?

Comment: am using tomcat server and this is the url am using http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorld/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp

Comment: Try localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorld/hello. You know, the request mapping you have on the controller.

Comment: i ran as u mentioned Gimby but still it shows the error..have i done any mistake in my code?

Comment: Change `<property name="suffix"><value>index.jsp</value></property>` to `<property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>`.

Comment: i changed and executed but still it shows the same. i mapped the url already so whenever i start tomcat the url comes in address bar http://localhost:8080/Spring4MVCHelloWorld/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp

Comment: You did mistake in **index.jsp** page. **U didn't give any call to your `/hello`**. If u add this `<a href="hello?name=ABC">Click Here</a>` line & click on it then only it will call your controller & forward the request to **helloworld.jsp** page.

Comment: Try using Spring Boot instead. It handles nearly all of this setup for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your **index.jsp** as

```
<body>
    <center>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <h3>
            <a href="hello?name=ABC">Click Here</a>
        </h3>
    </center>
</body>
```

modify **dispatcher-servlet** as

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Spring will resolve the view’s name **/hello** as

```
When request for /hello comes to controller it will redirect to helloworld.jsp.

prefix + view name + suffix = /WEB-INF/pages/helloworld.jsp
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @AsthCg Good to know you can now run your project.

Answer (score 0):

A correction is required in dispatcher-servlet.xml. Instead of using suffix as 'index.jsp' it should be '.jsp'. Second you should also point to the view type for example JSTLView. Here is a snapshot for your reference:

```
    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

I am assuming that your controller class is in package 'com.helloworld' and you are hitting a URL similar to 
hostname:port/AppName/hello
Where AppName is your Application Name, hostname could be localhost and port be default is 8080.